# Having problem in using 'GoDebug' plugin for Sublime

Tags: debugging, go, sublimetext3

I've installed the [GoDebug](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GoDebug) package using Package Control in Sublime text 3(Mac), and tried to run it by right-click > Delve > Enable.

It gives this Error:

> An open project is required

I also tried to manually put the following code in my project file `MyGoProject.sublime-project`

```
"settings":
{
  "delve_enable": true
}
```

*still, it doesn't seem to have any effect.* :(

or is there any similar plugin to debug go programs in Sublime effectively?

---

> Note: Please don't suggest other text editors (Atom, VS code, etc), that can't beat the speed of Sublime.

Comment: Have you installed `GoSublime`?

Comment: Yes, I am using GoSublime, it is really useful.
@AbhinavKinagi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, found the problem,

The project should be first initialized using `Project > Save Project As...`

Instead of doing this, I created a new project file named `MyGoProject.sublime-project` manually, 
so the changes made in the file didn't reflect in Sublime.